# Why does IsKnownColor not recognize all colors?

Tags: c#, winforms, colors

use this code:

```
Color c = Color.FromName("CarminePink");
if (c.IsKnownColor)
{
    MessageBox.Show("IS COLOR");
}
```

Why does this not recognize "CarminePink" for example. It recognizes some, and some don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`Color.IsKnownColor` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.isknowncolor(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets a value indicating whether this `Color` structure is a predefined
>   color. Predefined colors are represented by the elements of the
>   `KnownColor` enumeration.

And `CarminePink` is not one of the [`KnownColor` enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.knowncolor(v=vs.110).aspx) values. That's why your `c.IsKnownColor` returns `false`.

Comment: Oh... Is there a better way to see if it is a color then?

Comment: Oh, never mind. The controls it the form can't use these unknown colors anyway. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @spunit Looks like `CarminePink` is not a valid color when you look at with `Color.FromName` method.